# Concatenate two files whose paths are stored in variables

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've got two variables in Bash which contains log files:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=/var/script/content1.log
b=/var/script/content2.log

/usr/bin/mail -s "Test" -- mail_address < $a $b
```

Until now, I couldn't figure out a way to get both of the logs in the same email.

Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For once you get to use [`cat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) to actually *concatenate* files:

```
cat "$a" "$b" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Test" -- mail_address
```

<sup>(Don’t forget to quote your variables.)</sup>

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bash, you could use process substitution:

```
/usr/bin/mail -s "Test" -- mail_address <(cat "$a" "$b")
```